# Give curved line a deeper arc in turf.js and mapbox

Tags: javascript, geometry, mapbox, geojson, turfjs

There's no simple curved-line tool in turf.js, nor is there an easy way to do it in mapbox (so far as I can see), so I've created a workaround based on [this answer in this thread](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1218#issuecomment-356147495).

However, the curve it creates isn't very smooth or satisfying or has an inconsistent hump based on angle/length.

Ideally, I'd like an arc that is always in a nice, rounded form.
and drawing a line between them. I then offset the midpoint by `distance / 5` and apply a bearing. I then connect up the three points with a `turf.bezierSpline`.

```
const start = [parseFloat(originAirport.longitude), parseFloat(originAirport.latitude)];
const end = [
  parseFloat(destinationAirport.longitude),
  parseFloat(destinationAirport.latitude),
];

const distance = turf.distance(start, end, { units: 'miles' });
const midpoint = turf.midpoint(start, end);
const destination = turf.destination(midpoint, distance / 5, 20, { units: 'miles' });

// curvedLine gets rendered to the page
const curvedLine = turf.bezierSpline(
  turf.lineString([start, destination.geometry.coordinates, end]),
);
```

[image: Okay-ish curve, but a bit sharp]
[image: Curve is unbalanced]
[image: Should be straight up-down]

Desired curvature:
[image: Desired curvature]

Answer (score 1):

Well, that question was created a very long time ago, but I recently encounter this problem.

If anybody is still wondering - this code is good is general, but you've missed one detail. We can't use hardcoded bearing value `20` in `turf.destination` method, because it's incorrect for most cases. We need our moved midpoint to be right at the middle of our geometry, so we have to find the right angle.

```
const bearing = turf.bearing(start, end);
```

Then - if we want our arc to be on the left side of our line, we need to add 90  degrees to our calculated bearing. If on the right side - substract 90 degrees, so:

```
const leftSideArc = bearing + 90 > 180 ? -180 + (bearing + 90 - 180) : bearing + 90;
```

NOTE!!! Bearing is value between -180 and 180 degrees. Our value have to be calculated properly in case it'll exceed this range.

And then we can pass our bearing to destination method:

```
const destination = turf.destination(midpoint, distance / 5, leftSideArc, { units: 'miles' });
```

Now we have a perfect arc.